# How do I drop an object to the sand?

Tags: animation, objects, physics, transforms

When any object is dropped onto the material like sand in real life it changes it's surface like it's shown in the photo. 
[image]

How can I do it in Blender having the object and a subdivided plane that are shown below using physics?

[image]
Thanks for help !

Comment: Try using dynamic paint.

Comment: depending on what you wish maybe even a cloth sim could be made like that

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is whilst Blender has some excellent physics solutions. What you are trying to do could be a little past the scope of the current physics solvers.
There may be ways to do it using fluid particles or even the molecular add-on, although I'm not sure what the current skinning capabilities of these are.
I will however point you to a cool little tip from one of Nikolaus Gradwohl's blogs, showing denting using dynamic paint. This might help you towards your result.
http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2017/8/9/blender-dynamicpaint-displacement

Comment: This answer kinda look like "link answer only".

Comment: The molecular addon and cubesurfer addon can create stunning results to simulate snow, tearing cloth and sand but you have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html).

- For the sand object, enable dynamic paint and add a canvas, change the surface type to Displace.

[image: dynamic canvas surface setting]

- For the rock, enable dynamic paint and add a brush.
- Change the current frame or play an animation to have the displacement update.

[image: sample displaced mesh]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very crude 'proof of concept' based on Nikolaus' procedure. You may need to rebake all dynamics if the 'denting' doesn't show up. One could increase sim timesteps for better results, and even maybe add small particles that fall into the dents for further effect.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuw99bbvgiabhsw/hourglass.0001-0100.mp4?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge4kvem8g2oog2e/hourglass.blend?dl=0

Comment: ...maybe you did the file sharing really wrong...

Comment: It would be useful if you could summarize the steps taken for the proposed answer instead of just posting a file. Even downloading the file it might not be obvious what the procedure should be, or why you set the values the way you did. Other users with less experience might benefit from an explanation and might learn to adapt the tools for other projects.

Comment: Totally understand. However, I have limited time at the moment, and hoped that something, might be better than nothing, right now ;)'